# Undertsanding the different かける

Tags: word-choice, words

You know the verb かける? It has so many meanings my mind can't comprehend them all. Sometimes I feel unsure, so i'll look it up in the dictonary, however when doing so I can't help but feel overhelmed by all the different meanings. By the same word. Used for food when sparkling over salt or even recording music. I feel like it could be anything. I got particularly interested in this text where かける is being used quite a bit to explain word 乾坤一擲.

「乾」は「天」、「坤」は「地」、「乾坤」で「天地」の意味。 天地をかけて一回さいころを投げるという意味から、自分の運命をかけて、のるかそるかの勝負に出ることをいう。 韓愈の詩「鴻溝を過ぐ」の「竜疲れ虎困じて川原に割ち、億万の蒼生、性命を存す。 誰か君王に馬首を回らすを勧めて、真に一擲を成して乾坤を賭せん」から。([source](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ke/kenkonitteki.html))

Comment: Do you want to know what かける means in this dictionary entry then?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I was unclear, that is my question.  天地をかけて一回さいころを投げる. This part. And as well, 自分の運命をかけて.

Comment: Do you mean "*playing* music?" (音楽をかける, CDをかける…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 天地を**かけて**一回さいころを投げる
- 自分の運命を**かけて**

Both of these are using かける in the same way. I would say they both fit with the meaning of 賭ける or possibly 懸ける.

賭ける and 懸ける both involve *risking the loss of something*. In the case of this definition, risking the loss of 天地 (everything) and risking the loss of 運命 (one's fortunes).

There are basically 3 kinds of かける：

1. To be **lacking something**「欠ける」

   > お金が欠けている - (We are) lacking money
2. To **run quickly**「駆ける・翔ける」

   > 駆け込み禁止  - Don't rush (into the train)
3. To **lay something across/over something else** (and by extension
   , to risk loosing something)「掛ける・架ける（抽象的な意味では、賭ける・懸ける）」

   > - 壁に掛ける - Hang (something) on the wall
   > - 橋を架ける - Make a bridge
   > - 命を賭ける - Bet (your) life
   > - 命を懸ける - Risk (your) life

Comment: It is highly misleading to state "There are basically 3 kinds of かける" because, for one thing 「欠ける」 is not even pronounced the same way as 「駆ける」 or 「掛ける」.

Comment: Is the origin of 欠ける different from the others spelled かける?

Comment: It looks like in 文語 there are two conjugation patterns for 「かく」, ｛か／き／く／く／け／け｝and ｛け／け／く／くる／くれ／けよ｝http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F - But this difference only appears to affect whether the verb is transitive or not...

Comment: @l'électeur I'm curious as to what you mean by saying that they are pronounced differently. Do you mean the pitch-accent?

Comment: @sazarando Thank you very much. Your informative answer has cleared my doubts.

Comment: "over the weekend" 週末にかけて also exists. what is the meaning here, is it "run quickly"? @sazarando

Comment: @ジョハンソン I believe that usually would be,「週末に架けて...」（沖縄に行ってきた）as in (We went to Okinawa) "...over the weekend"

Comment: @sazarando thank you!:)